# Test the series for convergence if $\ \beta-\alpha \neq 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Test the series for convergence, if $\ \beta-\alpha \neq 1$,

$$1+\frac{1+\alpha}{1+\beta}+\frac{(1+\alpha)(2+\alpha)}{(1+\beta)(2+\beta)}+\frac{ (1+\alpha)(2+\alpha)(3+\alpha)}{(1+\beta)(2+\beta)(3+\beta)}+\ldots$$

I tried Ratio test, but it gives me $1$, which doesn't prove anything. Any hint?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to require $\beta$ is not a negative integer, to prevent division by zero?

Comment: Why $\beta-\alpha\neq1$?

Comment: By the way this evaluates to $_{2}F_{1}(1,1+\alpha,1+\beta;1)$, the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Answer (score 0):

if $\ \beta-\alpha \neq 1$, let the difference be equal to zero which is not equal to 1, and then you will get the series 1 +1 +1 +...  which is a divergent series

Comment: But what if the difference is not 0, the series could be convergent or divergent based on the values of $\ \beta$ and $\ \alpha$